# Inverse selection in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I invert selected objects in Adobe Illustrator?

I have made a group of different shapes and I want to apply two different colours on them. Is there is a way to invert selection?

Comment: Hi Haziq. Inverse selection in Illustrator is easy, but I don't see how it relates to applying different colours to objects. Unless you're talking about 'inverting' the stroke/fill of two objects – if this is the case, select the object you wish to 'invert' and then click the little arrow between the Stroke and Fill in the toolbar ('Swap Fill and Stroke') or click Shift+X.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Select > Inverse`. This will select everything *except* whatever you currently have selected.

Comment: Thanks Alex Select>Inverse is what I am looking for.In most programs there is shortcut Ctrl+I for inverse,in illustrator it does not seem have Ctrl+I shortcut any ways thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Straight Selection Gadget" in the Toolbox, in addition, to drag it throughout the important things you intend to change to downsides. To choose all the items, press "Ctrl-A" on the key-board. Click the "Edit' menu, select "Edit Color styles" as well as additionally click "Invert Shade styles."